3-bit grayscale is skipped on the monochrome list
I wonder why this Wikipedia list has 1-bit, 2-bit, 4-bit, 8-bit grayscale. But it skips the 3-bit grayscale. Does it have a specific reason?

Probably because noone/nothing uses 3-bit. There's no mention of 5, 6 or 7-bit greyscale either - doesn't that concern you? Note that the Wikipedia page for PNG is just the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG See section entitled "Critical Chunks".

Because no one ever wanted or needed 3-bit grayscale. In general, you would like for the bits to fit nicely into a byte, so 1, 2, 4, 8 bits would fit 8, 4, 2, and 1 pixels per byte. Or 16-bit grayscale into two bytes.
